# Maven - Dependencies in external libraries not copying over to target folder

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm working on a Java project. I am using Maven to handle the dependencies. I've added a couple of dependencies to the pom.xml file, but when I run the index.html file (in the project), which starts a TomCat server, the TARGET folder that gets generated - does not contain any dependency JAR files.

This is my first time using Maven. I've been looking around for this problem for an hour or two, but I can't seem to find an answer. I've read about plugins, but I don't understand how those work.

I am using IntelliJ IDEA with the Maven plugin.
I've got dependencies in the project, under External Libraries, handled by Maven.

I want the dependency JAR files to be in target > projectname > WEB-INF> lib.

Pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>demoblog</groupId>
    <artifactId>demoblog</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>demoblog</name>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>eap</id>
            <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>eap</id>
            <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.2-1003-jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.25</version>
        </dependency>     
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be used when 
                invoking mvn. -->
            <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app 
                will need. -->
            <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 'webapps' 
                folder. -->
            <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
            <id>openshift</id>
            <build>
                <finalName>demoblog</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory>
                            <warName>ROOT</warName>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Also add pom.xml in question.

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj Added, thank you for telling me.

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj I removed the line that said 'provided'  underneath the Jersey dependencies and... fixed it! No idea how it got there in the first place.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependencies with you tagged with `<provided>` are not in the (fat/uber-)jar, as you declared them to be provided by the runtime environment (i.e., your tomcat server).

Comment: Yep! That's exactly it. I figured that out about a minute before you posted it. I will mark your answer as correct, thank you for taking the time to figure it out with me.